# How far is a Wheel?

Tags: the-dark-tower

The inhabitants of Mid-World seem to use both `miles` and `wheels` as units of distance. In *The Wind Through The Keyhole*, Bix offers directions in the unit of Roland's choice - and Roland chooses `wheels`.

How far (in miles or kilometers) is a `wheel`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**This information is compiled from the [Dark Tower Concordance](http://books.google.com/books?id=fWvcU83jsooC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), a book of Dark Tower references by Robin Furth. The Concordance lists two different measures for a wheel based on two different books. I will list them both; the Concordance does not confirm one over the other.**

Wheels: An archaic form of measurement still used thoughout Mid-World and the BORDERLANDS.

- In *[The Waste Lands,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Tower_III%3a_The_Waste_Lands)* Blaine tells us that a distance of eight thousand wheels is equivalent to seven thousand miles. In that case there are about 1.143 wheels to a mile.
- In *[Wizard and Glass,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Tower_IV%3a_Wizard_and_Glass)* tricky Blaine tells us that 900 mph is the same as 530 wheels per hour. In this instance, one wheel is equal to 1.69 miles.

Comment: It *could* be both. We know that since the world has *moved on*, distances have been changing.

Comment: Adding to the confusion is Daria in *The Wind Through The Keyhole*, who says that one mile is .8 wheels.

Comment: Ahh... I'd go with the 'moved on' theory for that see also: our friend the Wordslinger has no capacity to edit for continuity. As such; why did I even bother looking up a conversion since I am trying to calculate the ratio for the time of the Eld. Since the variation seems to widen, from a 1:1 to perspective, I am going to say in the time of the Eld there was no difference; in the High Speech it was one and the low speech it was the other. Now which is which?

Answer (score 2):

In book 7, *The Dark Tower*, Susannah equates 120 wheels to approximately 100 miles (“perhaps a bit less”)